# Herfindahl index code in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have trouble with programming the Herfindahl index in Netlogo. I want Netlogo to calculate it. I have trouble telling the program the following formula:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl_index#Formula

I want Netlogo to report it and plot it. Help please :-s.

Comment: do you have any code so far?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I have problems with the summation element. Foreach?

Comment: nope, you can simply take the sum, i will write something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete working example. For your purposes, you just need the `calc-HI` procedure (and remember to call it in your `go` procedure) but I have given you a separate model so you can test it yourself. The way to test it is to run `setup`, then run `go` then `show HI` in the command centre. By inspecting the individual turtles, you can see their variable values and use a calculator to check the match for HI value.

```
globals [ HI ]

turtles-own [ val ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set val random 5
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  set HI calc-HI
  tick
end

to-report calc-HI
  let num count turtles
  let total sum [ val ] of turtles
  let herf sum [ ( val / total ) ^ 2 ] of turtles
  report herf
end
```

For plotting, all you need to do is `plot HI` in the plot widget.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was playing with the foreach function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of market-shares using percentages. Map each market-share to the square and sum them up:

```
;;e.g. let market-shares (list .5 .5)
to-report calculate-herfindahl [market-shares]
    report (sum (map [? * ?] market-shares))
end
```

If you want to calculate the shares based on actual shares. Map each share to a percentage, then apply the above formula:

```
;;e.g. let market-shares (list 30 40)
to-report calculate-herfindahl [market-shares]
    let market-size sum market-shares
    report (sum (map [(? / market-size) ^ 2] market-shares))
end
```